# Creating possible combinations from Hashmap

Tags: java

I have a HashMap like below

```
 { HHsize=[HHSize4+, HHSize1, HHSize2, HHSize3], 
   AOB=[AOB<30, AOB30_50, AOB60Plus, AOB50_60],
   Asp=[Asp=N, Asp=Y]}
```

I need to generate all possible combinations of the value pairs. As a Cartesian product For example.

```
 [[HHSize4+,AOB<30,Asp=N],
  [HHSize4+,AOB<30,Asp=Y],
  [HHSize4+,AOB30_50,Asp=N],
  [HHSize4+,AOB30_50,Asp=Y],
```

and so on.

How can we go about this?

Comment: If you always have exactly 3 items in the map, you can simply have 3 nested for loops, iterating over the values of each key.

Comment: use for loop that iterates through all the elements of first array, then a nested loop that iterates through all elements in second array... and so on...and create a n-tuple while iterating.

Comment: I might have more than 3 items which is the problem. I don't know how many items i will be getting.

Comment: Use list of hashmaps in that case

Comment: What is the type of you hashmap?

Comment: It is <String,ArrayList<String>>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Guava [`Sets`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html):

```
List<Set<String>> values = map.values()
                              .stream()
                              .map(HashSet::new)  // to set
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
Set<List<String>> = Sets.cartesianProduct(values);
```